# how do you define types if you custom select in a rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

My query looks like this:

```
@posts = Post.includes(:last_comment)
    .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN read_marks ON posts.id = read_marks.post_id AND read_marks.user_id = #{user.id}")
    .where(:postr_id => postr.id)
    .select("posts.*, read_marks.comments_cache as rm_comments_cache, read_marks.timestamp as last_read_at")
```

But when I call `@posts.each{|post| post.last_read_at}` it returns a string and not a datetime.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try using the ReadMark model?

```
@posts = Post.includes(:read_marks)
    .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN read_marks ON posts.id = read_marks.post_id and read_marks.user_id = #{user.id}")
    .where(:postr_id => postr.id)

@posts.each{|post| post.read_marks.timestamp}
```

This method is cleaner, and uses ActiveRecord in the way it was designed.

If you really want to use your original query, you can parse the date manually.

`@posts.each{|post|  Date.parse post.last_read_at }`

Comment: But why does the OP's method using `select` not return the `last_read_at` as a `Datetime` ?

Comment: I only want to return all the posts even if it doesnt have a record in the readmarks table.  the where statement gets applied to all the records returned, so the posts without a read_marks record gets dropped. that's what i've been seeing. i'm not sure if its supposed to behave that way.

@Zabba I think it has to do with activerecord using your migrations to set up the type.

Comment: My stab at the dark guess as to why this isn't working is that ActiveRecord only converts db values that are defined as a column in the table. This may not be done (or not done correctly) when the columns are not explicitly defined. I'll update my answer to do the join correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Even though `last_read_at` should be a `datetime` ActiveRecord does not automatically deserialize non-column values.  You'll have to parse the datetime yourself.

```
@posts.each{|post| post.last_read_at = Time.zone.parse(post.last_read_at)}
```